# How to draw multiple transit route in 1 map with googlemap javascript api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, routes

I used directionsService.

But when I drew the second route(transit with different origin and destination), it cleared the former route.

How can I draw the second route on top of the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create multiple DirectionsRenderer objects (one for each route)